# converting c++ to objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, malloc

I am converting c++ program to obejctive-c.

When the original C++ source code includes "malloc.h" and "tchar.h" then how can I convert

this code to objective-c?

I hope your help.

Comment: Why on earth would you use `malloc.h`? `tchar.h` is something Windows and Windows-API specific, you'll have some work on your hand to convert that. I'd say break it into two steps: 1) make a standard-conforming C++ program; 2) port that.

Answer (score 2):

Converting C++ to Objective-C is not a straightforward task — you can't mechanically translate from one language to the other and end up with something sensible. On top of that, though, tchar.h is a Windows header — which means this code is probably written to the Windows API, so lack of equivalent headers is not going to be the biggest hump here.

To directly answer the question about those, though: The Windows TCHAR type is most closely equivalent to the POSIX `wchar_t`, though Mac OS X has its own Unicode libraries (CFString for C and NSString for Objective-C) that offer a lot more. And malloc is included in the standard library, so as long as you're including any of the standard application frameworks or stdlib.h, you'll have it.